# How to avoid memory allocations in sparse expressions with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an application where the sparsity pattern is constant.  Lets say that my computations are in the form

```
sm3 = sm1 + sm2
```

However, even I have set the sparsity pattern to be the same in all of those operands, my profiler shows that most of the time is spent in allocating and deallocating the result matrix.

Here is my MWE:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace Eigen;

  SparseMatrix<double> sm1(2, 2), sm2(2, 2), sm3(2, 2);

  // Populate sm1 and sm2
  sm1.insert(0,0) = 2.0;

  sm2.insert(1,1) = 3.0;

  // Compute the result pattern
  sm3 = sm1 + sm2;

  // Copy the augmented pattern into the operands
  sm1 = sm2 = sm3;

  // This loop triggers a lot of new[] and delete[] calls
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    sm3 = sm2 + sm1;
}
```

Can those allocating operations be avoided?

Comment: `sm3 = sm2 + sm1;` will generate a temporary (`sm2 + sm1`), destroy `sm3` and then copy the temporary to `sm3`.  Does `sm3 = sm2; sm3 += sm1;` improve things slightly?

Comment: `SparseMatrix` is expected to be used on large matrices like 10000x10000 and much larger. For such matrices the overhead of new and delete is negligible. So, on what matrix sizes are you working on? and did you measure the cost of such memory allocation with a profiler?

Comment: @RichardCritten: unfortunately the same amount of allocating is there.

Comment: @ggael: I use much smaller matrices, ranging from 100x100 to 700x700. I usually have performance gains using sparse tech. when solving linear algebra systems, but have to rely on preprocessing tricks like this for preserving the pattern along the entire program. Yes, I have profiled the program from the beginning, and so I discovered that >90% of the time is spent on new, calloc, free and delete.  I asked because I have seen that the Eigen pattern is not thrown away always on assignment, but I don't know how to enforce that.

Comment: Depending on your system, you may be able to get a nice gain in performance by handling memory allocations yourself.  If you know that memory allocations will always be the same size or if thread safety is not an issue, etc.  These things can really make a large difference in memory manager performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible because sparse matrices are assumed to alias by default. For instance, if you do:

```
m3 = m3 + m1;
```

with the pattern of `m1` not entirely included in the one of `m3`, then evaluating the expression directly within `m3` would not be possible. In the **future**, we could enforce re-use of the destination memory with a syntax like:

```
m3.noalias() = m1 + m2;
```

In the meantime, since your matrices are small, you can workaround and even get higher performance by enforcing that the pattern of `m1` and `m2` are the same than the pattern of `m3` by adding some explicit zeros. Then, with Eigen 3.3, you can cast the sparse addition into the addition of dense vectors:

```
m3.coeffs() = m1.coeffs() + m2.coeffs();
```

Even if the intersection between `m1` and `m2` is small, you will get very high speedups (probably one order of magnitude) because you get rid of the memory indirections, and benefit from vectorization (don't forget to enable AVX with, e.g., `-mavx`).