# Preallocating memory for sparse matrix operations in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I'm writing a program using Eigen (an optimizer to be precise) that has a "hot loop" within which I'd like to avoid memory allocation whenever possible.

When using Eigen/Dense I've been able to organize things so that all my memory allocation is performed in the constructor (with judicious usage of .noalias() and inplace LLT factorizations) by computing the sizes of all the workspaces I need in advance and preallocating.

I'd like to do something similar with the Eigen/Sparse variant of the code (to the extent that it is possible). The constructor will require the user to supply sparsity patterns for all the data which I can use to determine the sizes and sparsity patterns for all the subsequent matrices I need, workspaces included. I need to perform 4 kinds of operations:

1. Sparse matrix-vector products
2. Cholesky factorizations
3. Schur complements of the form E = H + A' * B * A where B is a diagonal matrix and H,A are general sparse matrices.

My current understanding is as follows:

- I can use x.noalias() = A*y (A is sparse, x,y dense vectors) for matrix vector products with no problems
- I can perform matrix addition using coefficient wise tricks by padding with explicit zeros as in e.g.,[How to avoid memory allocations in sparse expressions with Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593324/how-to-avoid-memory-allocations-in-sparse-expressions-with-eigen). This is mostly for operations like B = A + s I where A is sparse and sI is a scalar multiple of identity. I can just make sure the main diagonal is included in the sparsity pattern of B and perform the addition in a loop.
- As of 2017, there is no way to avoid temporary allocation in sparse matrix products e.g., C = A*B (https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=140031&p=376933&hilit=sparse+memory#p376933), and I don't see any inplace functions for sparse matrices yet so I'll have to bite the bullet on this one and accept the temporary creation.
- For licensing reasons, I'm using an eigen external LDL' factorization package which allows me to preallocate based on a symbolic analysis stage.

Can anyone suggest a fast way to organize the Schur computation E = H + A' * B * A? (exploiting that I know its sparsity structure in advance)

Comment: This has been an open feature request for a while: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=385, if someone has a feasible solution for this, contributions are welcome :)

Comment: Note that `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT` is now MPL2, and it can also preallocate based on symbolic factorization, just call `analyzePattern(A)` once, and then `factorize(A)`.

Comment: If you know the structure of `A'*A`, you might try to loop over its non zeros, and for each non-zeros `(i,j)`, compute it as `(A.innerVector(i).cwiseProduct(b).dot(A.innerVector(j))`, with `b` a dense vector storing the diagonal of B. This should be quite efficient, but I'm not 100% sure this will be faster than allocating though.

Comment: Following the advice of @ggael I've solved the problem with:

`for ( int i = 1, k = 0; i <= AtA.cols(); ++i ) {
  for ( int j = AtA.outerIndexPtr()[i - 1]; j < AtA.outerIndexPtr()[i]; ++j, ++k ) {
    AtA.valuePtr()[k] = A.innerVector( AtA.innerIndexPtr()[k] ).cwiseProduct( b ).dot( A.innerVector( i - 1 ) );
  }
}`